# CSS3 Drop Shadow that's pushed in on both sides below the element

Tags: css, dropshadow

I'm trying to create the drop shadow effect like what's in the attached image.

The shadow with the code below appears directly beneath the element, but I need it to start about 20px from the left and 5px from the right.

Anybody have any tips on how to create this drop shadow offset on both sides?

[image: drop shadow effect]

```
.myDiv {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  box-shadow: 10px 0px 5px -2px #999;
}
```

Comment: Put the element in a container with another box, position absolutely inside container and give box a shadow. This allows for a lot of customization including rotated, shaped etc. shadows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building on @Ghost Echo's answer this can be done responsively using the [`::after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3a%3aafter) pseudo element.

Giving the pseudo element block display results in the element having `100%` width of the relative parent, so simply adding a `height:100%` makes the element match the parent completely. Then it was just a case of adding a margin to shrink the `::after` to the required width. The relative positioning and `z-index` are used to move the element behind the main `<div>` and the example `box-shadow` values are a close match to the image in question. You will probably need to change these to suit your exact requirements and also add a cross-browser `box-shadow` if needed.

[**See demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/kmeKx/) or code below.

**CSS**

```
.myDiv {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color:#fff;
    border:1px solid #eee; /* added for demo */
    position:relative;
}
.myDiv::after {
    content:"";
    display:block;
    margin:0 5px 0 20px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:-1;
    height:100%;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(153, 153, 153, 1);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="myDiv"></div>
```

If you need to [support IE8](http://caniuse.com/#search=after) change `::after` to `:after` as it only supports the old CSS2 syntax. There is no support for IE7 and below.

Answer (score 2):

this should do it or be close!

```
.myDiv {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  box-shadow: 20px 40px 2px -33px #999;
}
```

*Note: the last number is sort of a negative margin to reduce the size and the 40 pushes it down to still be visable*

Answer (score 2):

Here's a **fun** solution using the CSS `:after` psuedo class.

http://jsfiddle.net/CY2N5/2/

This way you'll be putting the box shadow on a `<div>` below the parent div that has the smaller dimensions. You'll have to adjust the box shadow to your liking. Just another solution ;-D

```
.myDiv {
width: 100px;
height: 100px; 
background:red;
position:relative; 
}
.myDiv:after {
content:"";
display:block;
width: 75px;
height: 100px;
margin-left:20px;
position:absolute;
z-index:-1;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
-moz-box-shadow:    0px 10px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
box-shadow:         0px 10px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}
```

A **repsonsive solution** can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/CY2N5/4/

Comment: Great example! What if it needs to be resized (so it's responsive)? How can that be accomplished since it's using absolute positioning?

Comment: Sorry, didn't see TreeMonkey answer posting exactly that !

Comment: @user2113311, answer updated with an example showing how to make it responsive. andyb did a great job explaining how these changes effect the elements.

Comment: @vals yes I saw (and upvoted) @Treemonkey's solution (and this one as well!) but I wasn't sure if the OP wanted an _exact_ margin left and right. The `::after`-less solution is nicer.